# mysql query - select distinct value where it has a specific values , group by

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I currently have

```
SELECT * FROM bidders 
WHERE status='0' 
AND email IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY `bid_user` 
ORDER BY 'bid_price' DESC
```

The problem that I have is that "bid_user" may exist in different rows with different status ( status=1 or status=0).
  I would like to know if it's possible to select only the * rows where status=0 and where bid_user doesn't doesn't exist with status=1 along with the above conditions(AND email IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY `bid_user` 
ORDER BY 'bid_price' DESC).
   I can work around this issue using PHP + 2 mysql queries but it would be much way better to have the exact query in mysql .

Comment: Does this query even work?  You're using GROUP BY, but you're selecting all fields, with no summary functions.

Comment: I think that the query should use "count" but I'm not very familiar with the sql query so I don't know how to use it properly

Comment: @george The query works . I'm using GROUP BY to get only records with distinct 'bid_user' and I order them by 'bid_price'

Comment: Ok, but GROUP BY needs to know how to roll up the result set.  Typically, any field not present in the GROUP BY clause needs to summarized somehow.  So, I still don't understand why it actually works.  What does the table look like?  The command "SHOW CREATE TABLE bidders" will provide the info.

Comment: @George Marian: To help satisfy your curiosity, MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` - see [GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html). This is why Michael's query is valid from a MySQL perspective.

Comment: @Marian the table is as following : CREATE TABLE `bidders` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `item_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bid_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `bid_user` text NOT NULL,
 `bid_member_id` text NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `verified` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `email` text,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20227 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @George Marian: Mike beat me to it, but fair warning - SQLite also supports the same "feature".

Comment: @OMG Ponies Oh, lovely!  @Michael  If you post that table structure in your question and use the code block to format it, so that I don't have to work too hard just to read it, then yes.  Of course, I'll try to help. :)

Answer (score 3):

As you want * rows with `status='0'`  AND `email IS NOT NULL`  don't use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * FROM bidders 
WHERE status='0' 
AND email IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY 'bid_price' DESC
```

EDITED (As per comment of @Michael )

Data

```
id  bid_price  bid_user status
1   100        test      0
2   200        test      1
3   300        test2     0
```

O/P Required

```
id  bid_price  bid_user status
3   300        test2      0
```

SQL Query

```
   SELECT * FROM bidders 
     WHERE bid_user NOT IN (select DISTINCT `bid_user` FROM `bidders` where status='1') 
       AND email IS NOT NULL 
     ORDER BY 'bid_price' DESC
```

Comment: @salil I forgot to add that I use GROUP BY to get records based on unique bid_user

Comment: my question is how to get rows with unique bid_user that have status=0 but also that don't exist with status=1 .

Comment: @Michael:- don't you think bid_user that have status=0 can't have status=1 as you say bid_user is unique and if it has that mean bid_user is not unique

Comment: @Salil In the bidders table i can have a situation
like this:
                  1) id=1  bid_price=100  bid_user=test status=0 ---
                  2) id=2 bid_price=200 bid_user=test status=1 ---
                  3) id=3 bid_price=300 bid_user=tes2 status=0 ---

So I need to get the all the rows that have status=0 with bid_user which doesn't exist in rows with status=1.
  If there exist 2 or more rows eligible with the same bid_user I need to get only one (here I use GROUP BY)

Comment: Using my current syntax I get the first and 3rd row . but as you can see  I need to exclude the first row because bid_user=test exist in in a row with status=1

Comment: @Michael:- Check my Edited Answer Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by replacing "status='0'" condition by "status='0' OR (status='1' AND bid_user IS NULL)"

Comment: can you please explain me the syntax status='0' OR (status='1' AND bid_user IS NULL) ? I'm not sure if I understand correctly but it seems to select the rows that have status=0 or the rows that have status 1 and bid_user "NULL" which is not what I'm looking for .

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which is likely to perform better assuming that you have indexes on `bid_user` and `status`:

```
SELECT 
  b.* 
FROM 
  bidders b
WHERE 
  status='0' 
  AND email IS NOT NULL 
  AND not exists (
    select 1 from bidders bx where bx.status='1' and bx.bid_user = b.bid_user
  )
ORDER BY 'bid_price' DESC
```